# How to make Eclipse RCP does not detect updates when only qualifier changed

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

I'm configuring the self-update mechanism for an Eclipse RCP application.
All is working like a charm excepting one point, here is the implemented flow:

1. Maven/Tycho generate the product and its p2 repository
2. This repo is copied/declared into a -public- composite repository
3. Update is detected and raised to user (of course in products installed from a previous build)

Fine ! But...

As the build rebuilds everything **features which did not changed are published into the repository with a new qualifier, and marked to be updated** :-(

Thing that I definitely want to avoid.

Reading this [Wiki Page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_(new)#p2.composite.repository) I thought to have found the solution by using the validate attribute of p2.composite.repository but it does not do the job. Here is my ant task:

```
   <target name="add">
     <p2.composite.repository validate="org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools.jar.comparator">
     <!--
          also tried with the other comparatorid
     <p2.composite.repository validate="org.eclipse.equinox.artifact.md5.comparator">
     -->
       <repository location="file:/local/www/productname/releases" 
                   name="Product Repository" compressed="false" append="true"/>
       <add>
         <repository location="http://localhost/productname/releases/1.0.0"/>
         <repository location="http://localhost/productname/releases/1.0.1"/>
       </add>
     </p2.composite.repository>
   </target>
```

All features from 1.0.1 are set to be updated even if just 2 of them contain changes and have their `major.minor.service` increased.

Thanks by advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reading this Wiki Page I thought to have found the solution by using the validate attribute of p2.composite.repository but it does not do the job.

I don't think this problem should be solved at the composite-repository level. Instead, the leaf repository should not contain changed qualifiers if the features didn’t change.

This is exactly what Tycho’s [Reproducible Version Qualifiers](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reproducible_Version_Qualifiers) are for. Provided your code resides in a Git repository, they synchronize the qualifier with the latest commit’s timestamp.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! I can't figure out how I didn't see this before... Thanks a lot Andreas